# "View all tags" left-aligned but "all answers" and "all badges" right-aligned in profile

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

In desktop version, in the profile tab of a user, the links to view all questions and answers and to view all badges are right-aligned, but the link to view all tags is left-aligned:

[image: view all tags link left aligned in profile]

Is there a reason for this? Can we right-align all those links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know in which build this was fixed, but the alignment is consistent now.